# Passport Local Authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I am new to javascript.I started a small project where i want to authenticate users.For this I have been using Passport local strategy.But the post request i sent on login button gives me error code 400 i.e. Bad request.I don't know what i am doing wrong.I have searched similar question but could not get an satisfactory answer to my problem.Below are code snippets.

**Login.html**

```
<md-content layout-margin class="center-form">
     <section class="md-whiteframe-7dp" flex>
          <div flex layout="column" layout-padding layout-margin>
           <form method="post" name="loginForm" layout="column">

                  <md-input-container>
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input ng-model="user.email" id="user" type="email" ng-pattern="/^[A-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+.[a-z.]{2,5}$/" required>
                  </md-input-container>

                   <md-input-container>
                   <label>Password</label>
                   <input ng-model="user.password" id="password" name="password" type="password"  required>
                   </md-input-container>

                  <md-button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login(user)" class="md-raised md-primary">Login</md-button>
           </form>
       </div>
   </section>
```

**Login.js**

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl',function ($scope,$http) {

      $scope.login=function(user){
      console.log(user);
      $http.post('/login',user)
      .success(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     })
  }
 });
```

**Server.js**

```
//Require Modules
 var express=require("express");  
 var config = require('./config');
 var path = require('path');
 var routes=require('./routes');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var multer = require('multer');
 var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data
 var passport=require('passport');
 var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
 var cookieParser= require('cookie-parser');
 var session=require('express-session');


//Init Express App
var app=express();

//Express sessions
app.use(session({
secret:"this is the secret key",
resave:true,
saveUninitialized:false
}));
//Cookie Parser
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/*Use Middleware (Between header to hTTP actions)*/
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing         application/x-www-form-urlencoded

//passport startegy 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,done){
console.log("username:"+username);
console.log("password:"+password);
return done(null,false,{message:'unable to login'}); 
}));


 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user.id);
 }); 

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
done(null, id);
});

// serve the static public files 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));  
app.use('/',routes);
```

**Route.js**

```
    var express=require('express');
    var router=express.Router();
    var passport=require('passport')

    router.post('/login',passport.authenticate("local"),function(req,res){
        console.log("Logged In");
        console.log(req.body);
    });

    module.exports=router;
```

I have read documentation of Passport js But it would be more useful to me if somebody could explain it in simple terms why 400 Bad request occurs on Login click.I have made post request on click of login button.

Answer (score 0):

If your form fields are not the defaults `username` and `password`, like they aren't, you need to provide options that contain the field names to `passport-local` like stated [in the documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/tree/c5a349b1fce71c51d66f78f8fc3e3861444b9a04#available-options). Otherwise you will [receive `HTTP Bad Request`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/c5a349b1fce71c51d66f78f8fc3e3861444b9a04/lib/strategy.js#L74-L76) because of missing login information.

Comment: Thank you @vesse .I found my mistake.The issue has been resolved.